# XOR on Unicode strings in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to decode an obfuscated Android app. After decompiling it, I can see that several strings are obfuscated in this way:

```
static char[] java_decode(char[] cArr, char[] cArr2) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < cArr.length; i2++) {
            cArr[i2] = (char) (cArr2[i] ^ cArr[i2]);
            i++;
            if (i >= cArr2.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        return cArr;
    }
str2 = new String(epgwmgrwgrdvzck("浶㫻ᒍ夓䌎箜湛泰Ⳮ䯣倝".toCharArray(), new char[]{'浌', '㫛', 'ᓮ', '奼', '䍻', '篲', '港', '沂', 'Ⲕ', '䯃', '倧'})).intern();
# java.lang.String str2 = ": country :"
```

For a better understanding and for a quick review, I'd wish to change all those strings into the plain one; I chose Python since it's just a quick and fast scripting language.
Sadly I'm having some hard times with those multi-byte chars. This is the function I tried to write:

```
# coding=utf-8

def decode(string1, string2):
    string1 = list(string1)

    i = 0
    i2 = 0

    while i2 < len(string1):
        string1[i2] = chr(ord(string2[i]) ^ ord(string1[i2]))

        i += 1

        if i >= len(string2):
            i = 0

        i2 += 1

    string1 = str("".join(string1))    
    print string1

    return string1

decode("浶㫻ᒍ夓䌎箜湛泰Ⳮ䯣倝", ['浌', '㫛', 'ᓮ', '奼', '䍻', '篲', '港', '沂', 'Ⲕ', '䯃', '倧'])
# TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

The main problem here is that `ord()` only accepts one character at time, while those strings are made of multi-bytes chars.
Any suggestions on how work around this issue?

I'm using Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64). I know Python 3 has a far better Unicode support than Python 2; if the solution only works in Python 3, I can use it without problems, as it's just a one-time script.

Comment: damn it, I was going to add the Python version and then I clicked on "Ask" without posting it. Thank you for reminding it

Comment: use Python 3. These Python 2 strings are analogous to Java `byte[]`, with unicode bytes in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as is (excepting that you need to change `print string1` to `print(string1)` in Python 3; the output and return value is the string `: country :`.

However, this doesn't work in Python 2, because in Python 2 the strings aren't *unicode*; you'd need to prefix all unicode string literals with `u`, i.e. `u'浌'` / alternatively you need to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to make '' create unicode literals in Python 2; and also `chr` converts a value into a 8-bit string value (i.e. a byte), not a unicode character.

---

FWIW, the code could be easier written in ***Python 3*** as

```
from itertools import cycle

def decode(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([
        chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2))
        for c1, c2 in
        zip(s1, cycle(s2))
    ])

result = decode("浶㫻ᒍ夓䌎箜湛泰Ⳮ䯣倝",
                ['浌', '㫛', 'ᓮ', '奼', '䍻', '篲', '港', '沂', 'Ⲕ', '䯃', '倧'])

print(result)  # prints ": country :"
```

First of all it seems that the java code allows the second array to be shorter than the first, and that in this case its value is repeated; in Python we can use `itertools.cycle` to achieve this effect more efficiently. We use `zip` to pair the corresponding values from the input arrays, and use a list comprehension to build the list that will be given to `''.join`.

This code can work with some minor modifications in ***Python 2***, by adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and changing `chr` to `unichr`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
from itertools import cycle

def decode(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([
        unichr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2))
        for c1, c2 in
        zip(s1, cycle(s2))
    ])

result = decode("浶㫻ᒍ夓䌎箜湛泰Ⳮ䯣倝",
                ['浌', '㫛', 'ᓮ', '奼', '䍻', '篲', '港', '沂', 'Ⲕ', '䯃', '倧'])

print(result)  # prints ": country :"
```